# how can I use ParseQueryAdapter for compund queries

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I'm trying to use the ParseQueryAdapter to give me a list of games. I have a separate table for storing game and player pointers. In the query I'm trying to list the games, and how many players there are. 
SQL style it is like this: SELECT games,count(players) FROM games JOIN participants...

I understand how can I do that with two different ParseQueries, but it only expects a single ParseQuery.

```
public class GamesListAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public GamesListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Games");
            return query;
        }
    });
}
```

How can I return a compound query here with counting all players from a different table?

Comment: In this question, are you asking how to construct a compound query? or are we to assume you know how to construct a compound query, you just need to know how to use it with a ParseQueryAdapter?

Comment: At that point in time I didn't even know how to create compound queries. Now I know that the I need to use whereKeyDoesMatch function.

Comment: @tothphu Could you please edit your question or post your solution as an answer, because I am in the position that you were back then and I would like to see some code in order to understand how to do it inside a parsequeryadapter. Thank you very much for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already found an answer yourself, but I post my solution here so other people may find it helpful.

In my case I have a `User` ParseObject and A `UserPhoto` ParseObject. I wanted to get only the Users' profile Images and set them in a `ListView`, but exclude the currentUser's(mine) profileImage from the results. Here is my working code.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseObject myUser = null;

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> myUserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                myDogQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                try {
                   myUser = myUserQuery.getFirst();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                ParseQuery<ParseObject> userPhotoQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserPhoto");
                dogPhotoQuery.whereEqualTo("imageName", "profileImage");
                dogPhotoQuery.whereNotEqualTo("user", myUser);
                dogPhotoQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");

                return userPhotoQuery;


            }
        });
    }
```

I would also like to see your code, if you have some time because I would like to see the "whereKeyDoesMatch function" implementation. Thank you!!